# Passing a value to an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Okay. Updated post with a complete background to understand the goal.

Creating a game where users pick two characters to duel. Each of the 'characters' is an object. Each object has a boolean property of `isAttacker` initially set to false. Those two characters are pushed into a `chosenChar` array.

When an attack button is clicked, I randomly pick one of the character objects from the `chosenChar` array that attacks. I then switch the `isAttacker` boolean to true. I also grab certain 'attacks' from an attack property array within the object and print that to screen. Whoever is not the attacker (with a boolean of `isAttacker` remaining as false) - I grab their "defense" power and print to screen.

That is all accomplished with this code:

```
 function attack () {

        attackChar = [];

        // get a random character to attack
        attackChar = chosenChar[Math.floor(Math.random()*chosenChar.length)];
        attackCharName = attackChar.name;


        // set isAttacker to true/false based on the attackChar
        chosenChar.forEach(function(char) {
            char.isAttacker = char === attackChar;
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < chosenChar.length; i++) {
            if(chosenChar[i].isAttacker === true) {

            } else {
                defender = chosenChar[i];
                defenderName = defender.name;

            }
        }

        // get a random attack from that character
        randAttackList = attackChar.attacks;
        randAttack = randAttackList[Math.floor(Math.random() * randAttackList.length)];
        $('#attack-text-row').html(attackCharName + " " + randAttack + " dealing " + attackChar.attackPwr + " damage.");
        $('#defense-text-row').html(defenderName + " blocks " + defender.blockPwr + " points of damage.");
    }
```

Since every time the 'attack button' is clicked a new attacker is drawn at random, I needed some way to keep logging their health and printing that to screen. I created a new function for that. Also, since I had no way of knowing which side of the screen the characters would be on, when the characters are initially chosen, I push a new keyword/property into their object of `placement`. That way I know if the defender is on the left or the right of the arena.

Here is my calculate health function. It's purpose is to grab the random attacker's power, get the blocking ability of the defender, calculate the net damage, and print to the appropriate character as it changes with each button click.

```
function caclulateHealth () {

        var netDmg = attackChar.attackPwr - defender.blockPwr;
        defender.health = defender.health - netDmg;
        console.log(defenderName + " health is " + defender.health);


        for (var i = 0; i < chosenChar.length; i++) {

            if (!chosenChar[i].isAttacker) {
                if (chosenChar[i].placement === 'left') {
                    $('#healthBox1').html(defender.health);
                } else {
                    $('#healthBox2').html(defender.health);
                }
            }

            if (chosenChar[i].placement === 'left' && !chosenChar[i].isAttacker) {
                $('#healthBox1').attr({
                    'style': 'width:' + defender.health + '%',
                    'aria-valuenow' : defender.health
                  });

                if (defender.health <= 50) {
                    $('#healthBox2').addClass('bg-warning');
                } else if (defender.health <= 25) {
                    $('#healthBox2').addClass('bg-danger');
                }

            } else {
                $('#healthBox2').attr({
                    'style': 'width:' + defender.health + '%',
                    'aria-valuenow' : defender.health
                  });

                if (defender.health <= 50) {
                    $('#healthBox2').addClass('bg-warning');
                } else if (defender.health <= 25) {
                    $('#healthBox2').addClass('bg-danger');
                }
            }
        }
```

I did, finally, get some of the code working for the progress bars. THe numbers are correct for the health value, but the progress bars sometimes INCREASE (meaning the character gained life). Again, the health numbers don't change, but the representation of the numbers do sometimes calculate incorrectly.

Here is a pic:

[image]

Comment: It's because you've missed the unit off the end of the value. `'width:'  + (defender.health * 100) + '%'`. Also note that you could just use the `width()` method for this, to make your code less verbose: `$('#healthBox1').width(defender.health * 100 + '%');`

Comment: Have toy tried: ` 'style' : 'width:' + (defender.health * 100) + "%"; 'style' : 'width:' + defender.health + "%"; 'style' : 'width: + defender.health' + "%"`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan neither of those worked to change width of the progress bar.

Comment: In which case could you please add your HTML and CSS to the question so we can see the context you're working in, and could you also double check the `defender` object to ensure its value is what you expect it to be

Comment: Updated post with HTML and pic of what's happening. The values are correct as I print them to the screen to make sure. I need to pass those values to the progress bar so that the css changes too.

Comment: Given the code you've shown, what I mentioned in the comment above works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7jennd2v/. Note the fiddle includes both variations. The latter of which will update the width after 2 seconds. If you still have issues, please update your question to show a working version of the problem in an executable snippet.

Comment: I completely updated the post. Hopefully that explains more of my goal and my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `px` or `%` (whatever required) and instead of using `.attr` use `.css`

```
$('#healthBox1').css("width", defender.health * 100+"px");
```

Or use

```
$('#healthBox1').width(defender.health * 100+"px");
```

Comment: @J.G.Sable is defender.health getting correct value? May be try hardcoding it once.

Comment: See the updated post with pic. defender.health is getting the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `%` symbol

## Your approach

```js
let defender = {'health': .25};
$('#healthBox1').attr({
  'style': 'width:' + (defender.health * 100)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<div id='healthBox1' class='progress'>
```

## Look at this code snippet

*This code snippet adds the symbol `%`*

```js
let defender = {'health': .25};
$('#healthBox1').attr({
  'style': 'width:' + (defender.health * 100) + '%'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<div id='healthBox1' class='progress'>
```